# Number of $H$-free graphs

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Sorry if this is basic for MO.  But the people at SE couldn't help me.

I'd like to get an estimate on the number of (labeled) $H$-free graphs on $n$ vertices, i.e. graphs in which no set of $|V(H)|$ vertices induces a copy of $H$. There are results on this, but I have some problems in interpreting the probabilistic arguments.
For simplicity, let $H = K_3$, a triangle.

Let $G$ be a random graph on $n$ vertices in which each edge appears with probability $1/2$.
From [this paper](https://www.ima.umn.edu/sites/default/files/393.pdf), we have that $Pr[G$ is $H$-free$] \leq e^{-c n^3/8}$ for some constant $c$ (see abstract, put $p = 1/2$ and $H = K_3$).

This probability seems very low, and I must be misinterpreting something.
Here's my problem.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of $H$-free graphs on $n$ vertices.
Then since $G$ is equally likely to be any graph on $n$ vertices, 
$$Pr[G\mbox{ is }H\mbox{-free}] = f(n)/2^{{n \choose 2}}$$

i.e. the number of $H$-free graphs divided by the total number of graphs.

But

$$
f(n)/2^{{n \choose 2}} = Pr[G\mbox{ is }H\mbox{-free}] \leq e^{-c n^3/8}
$$

implies

$$
f(n) \leq 2^{n \choose 2}e^{-c n^3/8} < 1
$$

for large enough $n$.

Hence there are no triangle-free graphs.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: The problem is that the paper does not give an $n^3$ factor.  For constant $p$, the minimum in Thm 1 occurs for one edge of the triangle.

Comment: Ah I see now..  I simply (and completely) misunderstood the $H \subseteq G$ notation.  Thank you for clearing that up.